# How to check the type of Kotlin variable

Tags: variables, if-statement, kotlin

I'm writing a `Kotlin` program where `type` of variable is `inferred` but later on I wish to know the what type of value this variable stores. I tried following but it shows following error.

```
Incompatible types: Float and Double
```

---

```
val b = 4.33 // inferred type of what
if (b is Float) {
    println("Inferred type is Float")
} else if (b is Double){
    println("Inferred type is Double")        
}
```

Comment: Did you try something like: val b: Number = 4.33

Comment: No I didn't. My point is can I extract the type of variable, without using Number type

Comment: You can. But if you write val b = 4.33 - it's the same as val b: Double = 4.33 i.e. you are already defined the type of variable. You have to choose way without that definition

Comment: @imGs ...Yes you can do it using b::class.simpleName . Please check my answer

Comment: Why would you want to dynamically determine a statically known type? Code smell, imho.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `b::class.simpleName`  that will return type of object as `String` .

You don't have to initialize type of a variable and later you want to check the type of variable.

```
    fun main(args : Array<String>){
        val b = 4.33 // inferred type of what
        when (b::class.simpleName) {
        "Double" -> print("Inferred type is Double")
        "Float" -> print("Inferred type is Float")
        else -> { // Note the block
            print("b is neither Float nor Double")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By checking this, the value of b does not follow the checking type. It is different by checking with `if (b is float)`

Answer (score 4):

Inferred type means that the compiler has retrieved the data-type of the object.

So, `val b = 4.33` is Double (based on kotlin compiler).

So it it assuming 'b' as Double everywhere.

In case you want a variable to assign to different data-types, you will have to use `Any` class

like

```
fun main(vararg abc : String) {
    var b : Any = 4.33 // inferred type of what
    println(b)

    if(b is Float) {
        println("Float")
    }

    else if(b is Double) {
        println("Double")
    }

    b = "hello"
    println(b)
    if(b is String) {
        println("String")
    }
}
```

outputs in

```
4.33
Double
hello
String
```

Here `Any` is same as `Object` class from java and can hold any type of data and you have to take care of object-type

Answer (score 2):

You have this error because your `b` variable is already `Double`, so it can't be `Float` anyway. If you want to test your `if` statement you can change variable initialization like following:

```
val b: Number = 4.33 // Number type can store Double, Float and some others
```

By the way you can replace `if` with `when` statement

```
when (b) {
    is Float -> println("Inferred type is Float")
    is Double -> println("Inferred type is Double")
    else -> //some default action
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to check type ,without using Number type for storing values of different types?

Comment: Well, you can make it `Any`. But what is your goal? Where from would you get variable to check its type? If you declare its type right in the function with check there is no need to check at all - you're already know its type.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're doing everything right. The error `Incompatible types: Float and Double` showed because you're assigning a const value (and to a val, so it wont change), that can be checked during compilation. That means that the compiler already knows of what type variable will be. But if the value will be obtained during execution, like this, than this check will do what you want.

```
fun main() {
    val b = getNumber() // inferred type of what
    if (b is Float) {
        println("Inferred type is Float")
    } else if (b is Double){
        println("Inferred type is Double")        
    }
}

fun getNumber():Number {
    return 12.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is neater way yet makes the value still follow the value checking accordingly in newest kotlin version.

```
when(b) {
    is Double -> println("Inferred type is Double") // you can use direct b as double in this checking section
    is Float -> println("Inferred type is Float") // you can use direct b as float in this checking section
}
```

below is example of use direct b in checking section without converting them to the expected type.

```
when(b) {
    is Double -> test = 3.0 + b
    is Float -> test = 3.0F + b
}
```